# Estimating a Gamma log-linked GLM model with 2SLS (IV estimation); question regarding the first stage estimation

Tags: regression, python, generalized-linear-model, endogeneity

here is a question I posted on StackExchange, but I was hoping if anyone here would also have insight in how to manually estimate a Gamma log-linked GLM model using 2SLS.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/73228998/19687003

Thank you!

"I want to estimate the following model using Gamma log-linked GLM and 2SLS:

`'Unemployment_total~log_usd_prize_y+Exports_gs+GDP_growth+CPI+log_GDP_per_capita+Country+C(t_Year)+Income_level+Income_level:log_usd_prize_y'`

The first stage being the following:

`'log_usd_prize_y~log_Internet_s+log_t_count+Exports_gs+GDP_growth+CPI+log_GDP_per_capita+Country+C(t_Year)'`

My log(usd_prize_y) is endogenous and I want to estimate it manually since Python does not have any package for estimating 2SLS using GLMs.

I have theorized that I would have to perform the first stage estimation using OLS, but I'm very unsure, and I'm not sure how to estimate the first stage using GLMs since the log-linked model has a different expected value formula.

Any insight would be helpful. Thanks"

Comment: Is your question whether you should do the first stage with OLS or with log-linked GLM? Or are you also unsure about what GLM to choose?

Comment: Sorry for me being unclear; my question is whether I should do the first stage with OLS (and whether it's something that is feasible), or also perform first stage with a log-linked GLM.

I already know that I have to use a Gamma log-linked GLM given that my data is right-skewed and heavily heteroscedastic (correct me if I'm wrong on that one too).